# How can I convert value of type 'SongViewModel' to expected argument 'SongViewModel' when I try to fix the preview for my SwiftUI Project

Tags: swiftui

So basically I am trying to make a music app in SwiftUI with a list of my favourite songs with a listView and detailView with a navigationLink. I am encountering some errors with the dynamic data though it keeps showing 'Cannot find 'songs' in scope' and I am struggling to find the solution to this. Could someone please help me I would really appreciate it.

```
final class SongViewModel: ObservableObject {
    private(set) var song: Song
    init(song: Song) {
        self.song = song
    }
}
struct Song: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let imageName: String
    let name: String
    let songs = [
        Song(imageName: "song1", name: "DJ NYK"),
        Song(imageName: "song2", name: "John Wick Deconsecrated")
    ]
}
```

So that is the code for my SongViewModel

And in my ContentView when I try to make the list it shows this error

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List(songs) { song in
                songRow(song: song)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

And in my detailView the preview shows this error
[DetailViewPreviewError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYVMf.png)

I would really appreciate if someone helps me with this thank you.

Comment: Have a project that you post code into. Then, the stuff that you put on Stack Overflow? Put it in that project first and make sure that problem can be reproduced. Otherwise you end up with a hodgepodge of stuff that compiles, and doesn't. Stack Overflow is not a rubber duck. You're supposed to post code that would demonstrate the problem for someone else.

Comment: What do you mean? I don't understand could you please explain it more clearly.

Comment: Needed minimal reproducible example and provide all related entities.

Comment: So what can I do to fix it? sorry I'm relatively new to Stackoverflow

Comment: You don't need to know anything about Stack Overflow. Just pretend like you're writing an email.

Answer (score 0):

We don't use view model objects in SwiftUI. We use `@State` which makes the View struct behave like an object. Try this:

```
struct Song: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let imageName: String
    let name: String
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @State var songs = [
        Song(imageName: "song1", name: "DJ NYK"),
        Song(imageName: "song2", name: "John Wick Deconsecrated")
    ]

    var body: some View {
        List(songs) { song in
            SongView(song: song)
        }
    }
}

struct SongView: View {
    let song: Song

    var body: some View {
        Text(song.name)
    }
}
```

However, usually the songs would be model data rather than view data. This means the data's lifetime is not tied to something being on screen and also gives the benefit you can use a different version for previewing. It's implemented using a Store object in the environment as follows:

```
class SongStore: ObservableObject {

    static let shared = SongStore()
    static let preview = SongStore(preview: true)

    @Published var songs: [Song]

    init(preview: Bool = false){
        if preview == true {
            songs = [Song(imageName: "song1", name: "DJ NYK"),
            Song(imageName: "song2", name: "John Wick Deconsecrated")
        ]
        }
        else {
            // load songs
        }
    }

    func save() {
        // save
    }
}         

@main
struct SongApp: App {
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView().environmentObject(SongStore.shared)
        }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var store: SongStore

    var body: some View {
        List(store.songs) { song in
            SongView(song: song)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView().environmentObject(SongStore.preview)
    }
}
```